Stripe error with prestashop payment module
I'm trying to use the Stripe module in prestashop and I'm getting this error in the Stripe dashboard
{
  "error": {
    "code": "resource_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
    "message": "No such customer: 'cus_XXXXXXXXXXXXX'; a similar object exists in test mode, but a live mode key was used to make this request.",
    "param": "customer",
    "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs/req_C8UwqThmn4P8?t=1729XXXXXX",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}

It seems like I need to create a brand new customer for the live use, but I don't know how to do that. Can anybody help me please ?

you have to create your customer first, where the customer is the same as your logged-in user.

The error message here tells you the issue:
"message": "No such customer: 'cus_XXXXXXXXXXXXX'; a similar object exists in test mode, but a live mode key was used to make this request.",

You've provided a test mode customer ID in a live mode request. Yes, if you're trying to use live mode you'll need to create a live mode customer first, the test mode customers cannot be used.
I'm not sure how Prestashop works to tell you have to do it there, but this is something you can also do in your Stripe Dashboard, and then you could use that new live customer ID.

Thanks for your answer. I understand, but I don't see how to generate a new customer ID in the dashboard... that's part of my problem...

For what it's worth : I have resolved my problem by adding a new customer ID, as suggested.
At the start, I thought that it would more like a profile within the same customer account, but I had to create a completely new one by going to the top left drop down where my original account name is mentioned, and create a new account, with all details again.
Then I had access to a completely new set of public and secret keys.
In the prestashop module config screen, I then did re-connect the plugin to my stripe account and could use the new customer id to bind to the new parameters. The plugin config got updated and I could use the stripe payment without any errors in the stripe logs.
